# Bypass OAuth validation when the request is a query

Tags: web-services, oauth, jax-ws, soapui

I have a web service which is validated by `OAuth` (Authorization code).
I am using `Oracle IDM` stack (OAM /Oath service , OES etc).

*The issue is* - I want to have OAUth validation only when a webService API is processed at the backend, but not when a client is just browsing a WSDL or XSD.

In  my current implementation, I am using filter in the `web.xml` and I have added web service name ( which is web service Servlet) URL in the filters. The url to browse the service and execute the service, will have same name except the `?WSDL` at the end of the URL,  in case of WSDL/XSD query.

So, the problem is when I query WSDL, then also it goes goes via OAuth validation, which I don't want!

I tried to add logic to determine if the http query string is `?WSDL` then by pass OAUTH validation, but it does not work because clients like SOAP UI and others can actually use ?WSDL in the URL, to even execute the web service API, which sort of fails the whole validation purpose.

Has anyone come across similar issue? how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Couldn't you put the WSDL somewhere else altogether?

Comment: Do you mean provide WSDLs and XSDs as a file access? I can do that but that will be totally manual step for web services consumers, We want to provide then URLs for the WSDL /XSD query , but without OAUTH validation

Comment: what happens when you access the url with `?wsdl` in a browser? doe ask for authentication?

Comment: There is a servlet that produces the WSDL. You could map that (and only that, not the parts that can actually serve the API and need to be protected by OAuth) to a completely separate part of your URL space.

Comment: @Rao, yes if in the browser - ?wsdl it will ask for the Auth. but if I add the logic to pass http query strings (?wsdl) then it does not. But the soap UI, or other client can embed the URL as ?wsdl and by pass full OAuth

Comment: @Thilo, Could you please provide more details on what kind of servlet is that - to provide WSDL only? I am using JAX-WS framework and SOAP services.